# Use EloquentUserProvider with different Hasher - Contextual Binding

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-5

I'm working on a project which has a legacy users database. I had to write my own Hasher class (which implements "Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher") in order to generate and check the existing hashes. This part was fairly easy and is working well.

What I'm having trouble with is getting "EloquentUserProvider" to use my Hasher implementation rather than the default "BcryptHasher".

Contextual Binding looks ideal in this case but I can't find many examples of it in use, so I'm really taking stabs in the dark.

Any ideas on how I can keep the default "BcryptHasher" for general hashing duties (eg. `Hash::make()`), while forcing "EloquentUserProvider" to use my Hasher class?

This is what I have so far (registered as a provider in "config/app.php"):

```
namespace App\Providers;

class LegacyHashServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->when('Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider')
            ->needs('Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher')
            ->give('App\Classes\LegacyHash');
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class hash does not exist

1.  in Container.php line 741
2.  at ReflectionClass->__construct('hash') in Container.php line 741
3.  at Container->build('hash', array()) in Container.php line 631
4.  at Container->make('hash', array()) in Application.php line 674
5.  at Application->make('hash') in Container.php line 1163
6.  at Container->offsetGet('hash') in AuthManager.php line 105
7.  at AuthManager->createEloquentProvider() in AuthManager.php line 91
8.  at AuthManager->createEloquentDriver() in Manager.php line 87
9.  at Manager->createDriver('eloquent') in AuthManager.php line 18
10. at AuthManager->createDriver('eloquent') in Manager.php line 63
...
```

It seems simple, but I'm puzzled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to my question.

After many attempts to get this to work I concluded that Laravel pre-built a "hash" object from the Service Container and injected that into "EloquentUserProvider". It did not use type-hinting to inject the dependancy, so Contextual Binding was likely not going to work.

In the end I essentially swapped Laravel's default Hash provider for my own one. I adjusted my "LegacyHashServiceProvider" and bound it to the "hash" key in the Service Container. Lastly I commented out Laravel's default Hash provider in my config/app.php file and added an entry for my "LegacyHashServiceProvider".

I feel Contextual Binding would have been much more elegant, if only it could have worked.

Here's the code from my "LegacyHashServiceProvider"

```
class LegacyHashServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', \App\Classes\LegacyHash::class);
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['hash'];
    }
}
```